# Instantiate domain model on every call,DDD

Tags: model, domain-driven-design, instance

When developing a web application applying DDD principles, do we need to instantiate the domain model on every application function call at Application layer? Say we have a shopping cart and user goes through page1->page2->page3 to check out. In each of the >Next> the system does some processing internally e.g. to update shopping cart with total, update the item count etc.

Answer (score 0):

We surely do not need to retrieve from persistence layer whole domain model.

We need to retrieve only related aggregate root. Tasks from UI should be bound to aggregate roots similarly as repositories are bound to aggregate roots.

If You mean do we need to always retrieve aggregate root on every request - then no.
Nothing prevents us to cache shopping cart in session for example.